# twitter api php or c#

Tags: c#, php, twitter

is there a way to get all friends/users for an account that dont't follow back?

I saw methods to get followers and to get friends. But ow can I determine::

a) since when I follow a special account
b) does this user follow me back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to tell if a specific user is following you use [GET friendships/show](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/friendships/show). If you want to know everyone who you follow that does not follow you back you will want to compare [GET friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/friends/ids) and [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/followers/ids) followed by [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup) to get their full profiles.

Comment: I see, thanks. And will I receive through GET friends/ids all ids (I mean if the number of ids are 10000) or do I have to use a cursor? If I have to use a cursor, how this can be done?

Comment: [GET friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/followers/ids) returns 5000 at a time so you will have to get the `next_cursor` value witch you will pass in the next request as the `cursor` parameter.

Comment: Okay, thank you. And if next_cursor of the result is 0, then the result is completed?